# Arduino Processing communication repeating action

Tags: image-processing, arduino, processing

I have made a robotic arm. I need it to capture video and detect blue and red color. And move the blue object to left and red object to right. But the problem is, whenever it is finding a color, it is supposed to send a character '1' (for blue) and '2' for red  to the serial port. My problem is, 
1. First of all it is taking a lot of time to react.
2. If it detects red. sends '2' to the serial port. But it repeats the action. Even if I change object.
3. Or If it detects red. sends '1' to the serial port. But it repeats the action. Even if I change object.

Color is being detected successfully. 
Please someone help me. I've got stuck for a long time.

My Processing Code:

```java
import processing.video.*;

import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort;  // Create object from Serial class
String portName;
Capture video;

color trackColorgreen,trackColorblue,trackColoryellow; 
float threshold = 20;
float distThreshold = 75;

ArrayList<Blob> blobgreen = new ArrayList<Blob>();
ArrayList<Blob> blobblue = new ArrayList<Blob>();
ArrayList<Blob> blobyellow = new ArrayList<Blob>();


void findcolorgreen()
{
for (int x = 0; x < video.width; x++ ) {
    for (int y = 0; y < video.height; y++ ) {
      int loc = x + y * video.width;
      // What is current color
      color currentColor = video.pixels[loc];
      float r1 = red(currentColor);
      float g1 = green(currentColor);
      float b1 = blue(currentColor);
      float r2 = red(trackColorgreen);
      float g2 = green(trackColorgreen);
      float b2 = blue(trackColorgreen);

      float d = distSq(r1, g1, b1, r2, g2, b2); 

      if (d < threshold*threshold) {

        boolean found = false;
        for (Blob b : blobgreen) {
          if (b.isNear(x, y)) {
            b.add(x, y);
            found = true;
            break;
          }
        }

        if (!found) {
          Blob b = new Blob(x, y);
          blobgreen.add(b);
         }
      }
    }
  }

}


void findcolorblue()
{
for (int x = 0; x < video.width; x++ ) {
    for (int y = 0; y < video.height; y++ ) {
      int loc = x + y * video.width;
      // What is current color
      color currentColor = video.pixels[loc];
      float r1 = red(currentColor);
      float g1 = green(currentColor);
      float b1 = blue(currentColor);
      float r2 = red(trackColorblue);
      float g2 = green(trackColorblue);
      float b2 = blue(trackColorblue);

      float d = distSq(r1, g1, b1, r2, g2, b2); 

      if (d < threshold*threshold) {

        boolean found = false;
        for (Blob b : blobblue) {
          if (b.isNear(x, y)) {
            b.add(x, y);
            found = true;
            break;
          }
        }

        if (!found) {
          Blob b = new Blob(x, y);
          blobblue.add(b);
         }
      }
    }
  }


}

void setup() {
  size(640, 360);
  String[] cameras = Capture.list();
  printArray(cameras);
  video = new Capture(this, cameras[3]);
  video.start();
  //trackColorgreen = color(11,77,28);
  trackColorgreen = color(159,211,207);
  //trackColorblue = color( 22,135,217);
  trackColorblue = color(195,173,175);
  //trackColoryellow = color(179,136,9);
 // trackColoryellow = color(221,228,125);
   portName = Serial.list()[0]; //change the 0 to a 1 or 2 etc. to match your port
  myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);

}

void captureEvent(Capture video) {
  video.read();
}



void draw() {
  video.loadPixels();
  image(video, 0, 0);

  blobgreen.clear();

  blobyellow.clear();

  blobblue.clear();

  //threshold = map(mouseX, 0, width, 0, 100);
  threshold = 80;

  // Begin loop to walk through every pixel
  findcolorgreen();
  findcolorblue();


  if(blobgreen.size()==0 && blobblue.size()==0 && blobyellow.size()==0)myPort.write('0');


  for (Blob b : blobblue) {
    if (b.size() > 800) {
      b.show();
      myPort.write('1');
      delay(2000);
      println("blue");
    }
  }


  for (Blob b : blobgreen) {
    if (b.size() > 800) {
      b.show();
      myPort.write('2');
      delay(2000);
      println("green");
    }
  }

}


float distSq(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) {
  float d = (x2-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y2-y1)*(y2-y1);
  return d;
}


float distSq(float x1, float y1, float z1, float x2, float y2, float z2) {
  float d = (x2-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y2-y1)*(y2-y1) +(z2-z1)*(z2-z1);
  return d;
}

void mousePressed() {
  // Save color where the mouse is clicked in trackColor variable
  int loc = mouseX + mouseY*video.width;
  color trackColor = video.pixels[loc];

}



class Blob {
  float minx;
  float miny;
  float maxx;
  float maxy;

  Blob(float x, float y) {
    minx = x;
    miny = y;
    maxx = x;
    maxy = y;
  }

  void show() {
    stroke(0);
    fill(255);
    strokeWeight(2);
    rectMode(CORNERS);
    rect(minx, miny, maxx, maxy);
  }

  void add(float x, float y) {
    minx = min(minx, x);
    miny = min(miny, y);
    maxx = max(maxx, x);
    maxy = max(maxy, y);
  }

  float size() {
    return (maxx-minx)*(maxy-miny); 
  }

  boolean isNear(float x, float y) {
    float cx = (minx + maxx) / 2;
    float cy = (miny + maxy) / 2;

    float d = distSq(cx, cy, x, y);
    if (d < distThreshold*distThreshold) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Arduino Code:

```java
#include <Servo.h>
Servo s2,s3,s4,s5,s6;
int pos; 
char val;

void setup() {
    s2.attach(3);
  s3.attach(4);  
  s4.attach(5);
  s5.attach(6);
  s6.attach(7);

  s2.write(90);
  s3.write(10);
  s4.write(100);
  s5.write(70);
  s6.write(15);


}



void grab()
{

 for(pos=15;pos<=85;pos+=1)
  {
    s6.write(pos);
    s5.write(85-pos);

    delay(20);
  }

  delay(50);



  // moving s3 forward
  for (pos = 10; pos <= 60; pos += 1) { 
    s3.write(pos);              
    delay(20);                  
  }


  delay(50);

  // moving s4 forward
   for (pos = 100; pos >= 80; pos -= 1) {     
    s4.write(pos);              
    delay(20);                  
  }



  delay(20);



  // moving s3 forward
  for (pos = 60; pos <= 70; pos += 1) { 
    s3.write(pos);              
    delay(20);                  
  }







  for(pos=85;pos>=15;pos-=1)
  {
    s6.write(pos);
    int x=-(pos-85);
    s5.write(x);
    delay(20);
  }
  s5.write(80);

  delay(20);





  //s3 initial

  // moving s3 forward
  for (pos = 70; pos >= 10; pos -= 1) { 
    s3.write(pos);              
    delay(20);                  
  }
  delay(20);

  // moving s4 forward
  for (pos = 80; pos <= 100; pos += 1) { 
    s4.write(pos);              
    delay(20);                  
  }

  delay(20);

}


void move_left()
{



  for (pos = 90; pos <= 180; pos += 1) { 

    s2.write(pos);
    delay(20);                      
  }

  delay(20);




  // moving s3 forward
  for (pos = 10; pos <= 60; pos += 1) { 
    s3.write(pos);              
    delay(20);                  
  }


  delay(20);

  // moving s4 forward
   for (pos = 100; pos >= 70; pos -= 1) { 

    s4.write(pos);              
    delay(20);                  
  }



delay(50);

  // moving s3 forward
  for (pos = 60; pos <= 70; pos += 1) { 
    s3.write(pos);              
    delay(20);                  
  }



  //expanding claw

  for(pos=15;pos<=85;pos+=1)
  {
    s6.write(pos);
    s5.write(85-pos);

    delay(20);
  }

  delay(20);


// moving s4 up
   for (pos = 70; pos <=110; pos += 1) { 

    s4.write(pos);              
    delay(20);                  
  }

delay(20);


  //s3 initial

  // moving s3 forward
  for (pos = 70; pos >= 10; pos -= 1) { 
    s3.write(pos);              
    delay(20);                  
  }
delay(20);

  // moving s4 forward
  for (pos = 110; pos >= 100; pos -= 1) { 
    s4.write(pos);              
    delay(20);                  
  }
delay(20);


  //For servo 1 rotation


  for (pos = 180; pos >= 90; pos -= 1) { 

    s2.write(pos);
    delay(20);                      
  }

delay(20);



  for(pos=85;pos>=15;pos-=1)
  {
    s6.write(pos);
    int x=-(pos-85);
    s5.write(x);
    delay(20);
  }
  s5.write(80);

  delay(20);


}


void move_right()
{


  for (pos = 90; pos >= 0; pos -= 1) { 

    s2.write(pos);
    delay(50);                      
  }

  delay(50);





  delay(50);

  // moving s3 forward
  for (pos = 10; pos <= 60; pos += 1) { 
    s3.write(pos);              
    delay(50);                  
  }


  delay(50);

  // moving s4 forward
   for (pos = 100; pos >= 70; pos -= 1) { 

    s4.write(pos);              
    delay(50);                  
  }



delay(50);

  // moving s3 forward
  for (pos = 60; pos <= 70; pos += 1) { 
    s3.write(pos);              
    delay(50);                  
  }



  //expanding claw

  for(pos=15;pos<=85;pos+=1)
  {
    s6.write(pos);
    s5.write(85-pos);

    delay(20);
  }

  delay(50);


// moving s4 up
   for (pos = 70; pos <=110; pos += 1) { 

    s4.write(pos);              
    delay(50);                  
  }

delay(50);
  // s3.write(10);
   //delay(500);
  //s4.write(100);


  //s3 initial

  // moving s3 forward
  for (pos = 70; pos >= 10; pos -= 1) { 
    s3.write(pos);              
    delay(50);                  
  }
delay(50);

  // moving s4 forward
  for (pos = 110; pos >= 100; pos -= 1) { 
    s4.write(pos);              
    delay(50);                  
  }
delay(50);


  //For servo 1 rotation



  for (pos = 0; pos <= 90; pos += 1) { 

    s2.write(pos);
    delay(50);                      
  }

  delay(50);

  for(pos=85;pos>=15;pos-=1)
  {
    s6.write(pos);
    int x=-(pos-85);
    s5.write(x);
    delay(20);
  }
  s5.write(80);

  delay(50);
}

void loop() {
 if (Serial.available()) 
   { 
     val = Serial.read(); // read it and store it in val

     if(val=='1')
     {
         grab();
         delay(200);
         move_left();
         delay(200);
     }


     else if(val=='2')
     {
         grab();
         delay(200);
         move_right();
         delay(200);

     }
   }
}
```

My robot:

[https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9JjLX3LHgUSSU40U3YzOU1LYXc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5OE.jpg)

Comment: Then benchmark your code if it performs badly. You have a double-for loop iterating through every pixel of a frame of a video, plus additional 6 function calls to get the color, plus calculations about the distance and another for loop to go through all blobs. That's a lot things to do, if the video is `1280 x 720p @ 30fps` then that's around 27 Million pixels  per seconds to process (if it was realtime). Consider using OpenCV for faster detection of blue / red spots, Java is not build for this.

Comment: I know that. I'm not using very high resolation camera. My image processing is working fine. The main problem is arduino performance.  I'll work out with opencv later. First help me to solve this problem. Image processing is performing fast in real time. Thanks Garhardt

Comment: By `First of all it is taking a lot of time to react` did you mean the **Arduino** (moving the robot arm when it receives a serial port message) or the **Java App** detecting the color? Well on the Aarduino you have the main problem that once it receives a value, it moves the arm into that direction and cannot be interrupted, since all the code is synchronous and only `delay()`s. If it get's a `1` you have to wait all the way for it to finish. You should include some sort of `ACK` from the Arduino to get some timings on how long `grab()` and `move_left()` (+ 400ms delay) takes.

Comment: You are not getting my point. I want to do the whole thing if '1' received. But, after performing 1's task, if it receives '2', it should do the other thing. But it is not doing that. It is doing the first thing.Thanks again Gerhardt.

Comment: Then you should test the Arduino code separately. Might this be an issue with your motor? `for(int i=0;i < 10; i++) { grab(); delay(200); if(i % 2 == 0) move_left(); else move_right(); delay(200); } while(1) delay(1000);` should do 10 turns, 5 left and 5 right.

Comment: I've tried this too. It is working fine. I think you are not getting my point. Suppose it has got '1' then it should go to left. It is going left. Or if '2' it is going right. This is alright. But it is repeating the first thing.

Comment: Your Arduino side with the receiving seems fine - add logging to your Andrdoid application to check all data that is sent out. The `for (Blob b : blobblue) { .. }` could be causing this.